# Problem installing packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-installation

I can't install any package, as I get this error:

```
installArchives() failed: E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg: regarding .../libgcc1_1%3a4.7.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb containing libgcc1:amd64, pre-dependency problem:
 libgcc1 pre-depends on multiarch-support
  multiarch-support is unpacked, but has never been configured.

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.7.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing libgcc1:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.7.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6:amd64:
 libc6:amd64 depends on libgcc1; however:
  Package libgcc1 is not installed.
 libc6:amd64 depends on tzdata; however:
  Package tzdata is not installed.

dpkg: error processing libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of multiarch-support:
 multiarch-support depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-2); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing multiarch-support (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: @EliahKagan I believe this is a different one. Looking at the info in the links you provided I don't see similar error messages.

Comment: @gertvdijk I think you're right. The `debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory` message is similar, but I see what you mean: In this question, that message is secondary to `installArchives() failed: E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?` In [that one](http://askubuntu.com/q/233260/22949) it's the primary error message (no other error clearly occurring first to explain it).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here the solution for this problem, super easy way ;)

You have to use dpkg direct to solve this problem sometimes.

"Here we go again"

The package `multiarch-support is unpacked, but has never been configured` this means the package soon will configure, but is not configured yet.

When is the status `unpacked` the package is not installed yet, so the package `libgcc1` cannot install because of the dependency is not installed yet and cannot be installed before `multiarch-support`.

We have to force the installed status for multiarch-support to do the trick.

```bsh
nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

find the the line starting with `Package:` 
something like:

```bsh
Package: multiarch-support
Status: install ok unpacked
```

You have to change the `unpacked` to `installed`

Now try:

```bsh
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
sudo apt-get install --reinstall multiarch-support libgcc1 debconf
```

I think you can get the system working again this way, let me known if you can do.

Comment: This fixed a slew of issues I was having on Raspbian with Pixel, including the UI based package manager. My `/var/lib/dpkg` directory was completely missing, so I did have to create that and a few directories underneath it when it complained, but in the end, this now allows me to use `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `/var/lib/dpkg` directory with its contents is screwed up. Mainly because of this line, I think your package management is unrecoverable broken.

> ```
> multiarch-support is unpacked, but has never been configured.
> ```

Additionally,

> ```
> apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
> ```

Means that `/usr/bin/apt-extracttemplates` is not available on your system, which is *really* out of the ordinary.

This does not break by itself; either data corruption or user error (e.g. `rm -rf files-you-should-never-delete`) is the cause of this. My best bet would be on backing up your data (e.g. `/home`) and start with a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you do not have `debconf` installed. To install it or check if it is installed, type `sudo apt-get install debconf` in a terminal. You can bring up a terminal by pressing `CTRL-ALT-T` simultaneously.

This will install `debconf` if it isn't installed and upgrade it if it is installed but out-of date or do nothing if it is up-to-date.

Comment: I do this, but It dosen't help.

Comment: I get this:
debconf : PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.6.1-4) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: @Mj125 Do this: `sudo apt-get install perl-base`

Comment: no, I can't install any thing.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install perl-base debconf`. Try this. Two packages shouldn't be interdependent.

Comment: I get this:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Depends: libgcc1 but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
 perl-base : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.14.20)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Did you try doing `sudo apt-get-f install`?

Comment: yes, but it dosen't help

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.7.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @Mj125 It seems likely that the problem could be solved by manually downloading the necessary `.deb` packages and installing them all together with `dpkg`. But first, please update your question by editing it to include the information in comments here (especially the error messages). Please also include the output of `dpkg -l | grep -E 'debconf|libc6|libgcc1|libgcc1|tzdata|perl-base'`, as that will reveal what if any versions of any of these packages may actually be installed. (After editing your question, if you comment with `@EliahKagan` in the comment, I'll be notified.)

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem because I have deleted /var/lib/dpkg/available, but now mine back normally after I do these steps

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

source: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/70504

Comment: Could you describe in your answer what you did to solve the problem? Keep the link just for reference.