# I can't install any package, dependency problems

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

The `apt-get` command doesn't work. When I try this `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, I get this:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6:amd64:
libc6:amd64 depends on libgcc1; however:
Package libgcc1 is not installed.
libc6:amd64 depends on tzdata; however:
Package tzdata is not installed.

dpkg: error processing libc6:amd64 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of multiarch-support:
multiarch-support depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-2); however:
Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing multiarch-support (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:

libc6:amd64

multiarch-support
```

The architecture of my system is amd64.

Comment: The architecture of your system is x32 or x64? Please, edit your answer telling us the output of the `sudo apt-get install (something)` command.

Answer (score 0):

Been there, you've tried to install something made for a different release. It's repairable but reinstall is quicker, specially if your `/home` isn't part of root (`/`) mount point.

Comment: The architecture of my system is  x64.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install dependency name
```

Sometimes dependency problems are caused by the dependencies being in a different repo than you have, like in cinnamon there are 2 repos for it. You need the right one to get all the packages for it

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution in another question:

https://askubuntu.com/a/485293/130195

But here you have to force the status the `libc6` to `installed`.

Read my other answer to understand how to force status `installed` to a package.