# Accidentally removed /var folder then turned off

Tags: boot, backup, restore, rm

I did something even dumber than [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586538/accidentally-removed-var-folder), which accidentally removed the /var folder. I then turned off the computer. Now, I can't turn back in. When booting, it stays blocked at

```
/var/lib/snaps/snaps/skype_274.snap: Can't open blockdev
```

Is there a way to restore a Back-up from the recovery mode? What can I do?

Does it mean I need to reinstall? If so, will I lose all my data?

EDIT: My OS is Ubuntu 20.04. I don't remember what backup I put in place.

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details. I'm a Lubuntu user mostly (*Lubuntu being a Ubuntu system*) and I have systems I don't perform upgrades on, instead performing a QA (*Quality Assurance*) test on them ~weekly & perform my upgrade of packages that way... ie. ensuring the non-destructive re-install worked flawlessly & none of my data/settings was impacted.. (*I don't specifically test for snap packages; Lubuntu doesn't ship with any beyond `firefox`*) but we don't know what system you're talking about currently so we'd be guessing. You can re-install non-destructively. You're using?

Comment: If you're after advice on restoring your backups... you'll have to tell us what backup system you put in place & were using, before we can help you with that. Given we don't even know your OS/release details, we'd only be guessing.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post. I am on Ubuntu 20.04.