# dpkg configuration errors installing RuneScape's NXT Client in a debootstrap chroot

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, udev, debootstrap

I have installed 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 in a debootstrap chroot, so that I can install the RuneScape NXT Client in this chroot, and with some luck this could be used to run RuneScape on platforms other than Ubuntu 14.04. But when I ran `apt-get install -y runescape-launcher` in this chroot I got the error:

```
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Setting up aspell-en (7.1-0-1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
Processing triggers for dictionaries-common (1.20.5) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 initramfs-tools
 dmsetup
 libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64
 mountall
 plymouth
 libcryptsetup4
 systemd
 systemd-services
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
 upstart
 dbus
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/485293/93125) to a previous question here namely editing `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` replacing `unpacked` with `installed`, then running:

```
dpkg --configure --pending
apt-get install --reinstall udev initramfs-tools dmsetup libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 mountall plymouth libcryptsetup4 systemd systemd-services libpam-systemd:amd64 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text upstart dbus
```

but it fails, with the first command returning:

```
Setting up udev (204-5ubuntu20.20) ...
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
 * udev requires hotplug support, not started
   ...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
```

Comment: How did you set up your chroot ? did you mount /sys and /proc ?

Comment: Sure do I execute these commands before I chroot into it https://gist.github.com/fusion809/22f3f1dd2ca75bfa0d44bae5efac2e32.

Comment: I suggest you try lxc rather then chroot and file a bug report.